# How do i add to a simple array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, string, addition

If I have

`Dim a As String() = ("One,Two").Split(",")`

How can I add to that string ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to add an Item to an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097756/fastest-way-to-add-an-item-to-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert it to a List and then add.

```
Dim a As List(Of String) = ("One,Two").Split(",").ToList
a.Add("Three")
```

or if you really want to keep an array.

```
    Dim a As String() = ("One,Two").Split(",")
    Dim b as List(Of String) = a.ToList
    b.Add("Three")
    a=b.ToArray
```

And here is something really outside the box:

```
a = (String.Join(",", a) & ",Three").Split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

For a different approach, try:

```
Dim a As String() = ("One,Two").Split(CChar(","))
Debug.Print(CStr(UBound(a)))
ReDim Preserve a(9)
Debug.Print(CStr(UBound(a)))
```

The output to the immediate window is:

```
1
9
```

Note: I have had to slightly change your original line because I always use `Option Strict On` which does not permit implicit conversions.